# How to resize HTML form submit button?

Tags: html, css, forms

I have simple HTML form styled with CSS. I tried to resize the size of submit button with `height` attribute but It is not working for some reasons. I tried the `width` attribute and it works. The `font-size` attribute increase the height of the button to some extent but when the `font-size` increases `20px`, then it also does not work.

I am using Safari browser.

```css
div {
  background-color:cadetblue;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px black solid;
}
form {
  margin-left: -15px;
}
label {
  display:block;
}
fieldset {
  border: none;
  display: inline;
}
input[type="submit"] {
  padding: 0px;
  height: 5em;
}
input[type="text"] {
  margin-left: 0px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>HTML FORM: nameform.htm - programmed by {Maihan Nijat!}</p>   
  <form method="post" action="greeting.php"> 
    <fieldset> 
      <label for="firstname" >Please enter your first name:</label> 
      <input name="firstname" type="text" />
    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit!" />
  </form>
  <hr> 
  <p>Copyright © 2014 <a href="http://www.php.net">The PHP Web Site</a>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: `input[type='submit']` change the height, you have 5em change it to 3em or use px.

Comment: Were you trying to change it somewhere other than in the CSS? Because the CSS you have does change the height.

Comment: @BSMP This `height: 5em;` doesn't work.

Comment: it works in firefox, wich browser are you using/testing ?

Comment: It also works in IE and Chrome.

Comment: Down-vote for what? Any explanation?

Comment: @GCyrillus I am using Safari. Answer is provided. Thanks

Comment: @BSMP I am using Safari. Answer is provided. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `-webkit-appearance: none;`  to your styles for the submit button. This keeps webkit from fighting your styles.

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/appearance/

```css
div {
  background-color:cadetblue;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px black solid;
}
form {
  margin-left: -15px;
}
label {
  display:block;
}
fieldset {
  border: none;
  display: inline;
}
input[type="submit"] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance:    none;
  appearance:         none;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 5em;
}
input[type="text"] {
  margin-left: 0px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>HTML FORM: nameform.htm - programmed by {Maihan Nijat!}</p>   
  <form method="post" action="greeting.php"> 
    <fieldset> 
      <label for="firstname" >Please enter your first name:</label> 
      <input name="firstname" type="text" />
    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit!" />
  </form>
  <hr> 
  <p>Copyright © 2014 <a href="http://www.php.net">The PHP Web Site</a>
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing it to a `button` element like so: https://jsfiddle.net/f3nuthn7/

Then you can customize it with stuff like this:

```
button {/* Customize the button here*/
  font-size:20px;
  width:200px;
  height:150px;
  background:lightblue;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Change this property in your css.

```
input[type="submit"] {
     height: 5em;
}
```

Comment: How will removing the `height` property from the CSS cause the specified height to be applied?